# Paragraph in a nav/ul/li position & placement

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that I have styled with CSS... Now, I want to place some normal text in the navigation bar, but it gets totally misplaced and I find it very hard to move, as it does not react at all to `text-align` or `bottom`. The text gets placed above the navigation menu, and it creates an White space.

This is my CSS for the navigation bar:

```
#nav{
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper{
    width: 960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
/*  font: Batang; */
}

@font-face { font: Batang; src: url('batang.tff'); } 

#nav_wrapper .current{
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #333;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
#nav ul li a,visited{
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover{
    color; #ccc
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav ul ul li{
    display: block;
}
#nav ul u li a,visited{
    color; #ccc;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: #099;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

This is the text I try to add:

```
<p class="logo">IVERSEN</p>
```

The navigation menu's buttons are in the right side, I want to add the text to the left.

This is the styling I have done for the text:

```
#nav_wrapper .logo{
color: gold;
font-size: 60px;
font-family: Batang;
/*width: 150px;
margin-bottom: -50px;
padding-top: -500px;*/
```

The only thing that seemed to Work (as for getting the text moved) was Width.

I have tried everything I can think of... So thought you Guys might be able to help me out on this one.

In case needed, this is my navigation bar in HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="home.html">Hjem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Om</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Projekter<img src="images\arrow.png"/></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Batch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show the entire markup snippet, please. Where does the paragraph go relative to the list?

Comment: Here's a start. Maybe fix it up to better show your attempt and post an updated URL in your question. http://jsfiddle.net/6j89s5hg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `float: left` to your new element to give it the correct position, but don't forget to the a `max-width` to your `<ul>` so it doesn't push the other element out. Also I removed the `margin` of the new element to make it fit within the black background.

```css
#nav{
    background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper{
 width: 960px;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 18px;
/* font: Batang; */
}

@font-face { font: Batang; src: url('batang.tff'); } 

#nav_wrapper .current{
 background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
    max-width: 800px;
}
#nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li img{
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
 background-color: #333;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}
#nav ul li a,visited{
 color: #ccc;
 display: block;
 padding: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover{
 color; #ccc
 text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}
#nav ul ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 border: 5px solid #222;
 border-top: 0;
 margin-left: -5px;
 min-width: 200px;
 text-align: left;
}
#nav ul ul li{
 display: block;
}
#nav ul u li a,visited{
 color; #ccc;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover{
 color: #099;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

#nav_wrapper .logo{
position: relative;
    float: left;
    color: gold;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: Batang;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_wrapper">
<div id="nav">
<p class="logo">IVERSEN</p>
<ul>
<li><a class="current" href="home.html">Hjem</a></li><li>
<a href="#">Om</a></li><li>
<a href="#">Kontakt</a></li><li>
<a href="#">Projekter<img src="images\arrow.png"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Batch</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Float, ah, should've known. Thank you so much! Works perfectly :)
Though, I want the entire navigation bar to move with scroll... So, bar follows you, will the Position ruin that